# join 2 columns and get only matched vlaues in hibernate

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa, nhibernate, hql

I have 2 tables:

```
 course: id, name
 student: id, course_id, age
```

Tables are tied with oneToMany annotation

I am trying to write a hibernate query against course that will return courses and students that are x years 0ld. That's my attempt:

```
SELECT c from Course c RIGHT JOIN  c.student p ON p.age = 20
```

It returns a course that has at least one student that is 20. when there are more students that are not 20, they are included in the result set as well. Is there a way to restrict the joined table values?

Edit:
These are my entities:

```
public class Course implements Serializable {

     private static final long serialVersionUID = 646349111982187812L;

     @Id
     @Column(name = "id", unique=true, nullable=false)
     private String id;
     @Column(name = "name", unique=false, nullable=false)
     private String name;

     @OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL, CascadeType.REMOVE}, 
     fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "Course")  
     @OrderBy("age")
     @JsonManagedReference
     private Set<Student> students; 

 getters and setters ...
}

public class Student implements Serializable {

     private static final long serialVersionUID = 646349221337813L;


     @Id
     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
     private Long id;

     @Column(name = "age", unique=false, nullable=true)
     private String age;

     @ManyToOne()
     @JsonBackReference
     private Course course; 
}
```

I am trying to use this method from my crudrepository to get the expected result:

```
 @Query(?????)
 public List<Course> findCoursesWithAdults(@Param("age")int age)
```

Answer (score 1):

it sounds like you want an inner join instead of a right join

SQL

`SELECT distinct c.* from Course c inner join Student p on (c.id=p.course_id and p.age=20)`

or with hql

`select distinct c from Course c inner join c.student p with p.age=20`

in order to get the information you are requesting, you will either have to limit the Set in Course using @Where ("age = 20" ) or simply deal with a list of students instead of courses.

`select p from Course c inner join c.student p with p.age=20`

you can reference the attached course object through any one of the getCourse methods on the student objects. You could also use "group by" here to help you order things.

or you can use a filter within the hibernate Entity...

`@Transient
    public List<Students> getStudents(Integer age){
        List<Students> tmp = new ArrayList<>();
         for(Student s: getStudents())
           if(s.getAge().equals(age))tmp.add(s);
    return tmp;
}`

one more edit and im done... there is another way to do this that i didnt mention..

a select wrapper query.

create a wrapper object for your course and student

`public class CourseWrapper(){
    private Course c;
    private List<Students> p = new ArrayList<>();
 ....constructor ... getters ...setters
}`

`select new CourseWrapper(c, students)
from Course c
    left outer join c.students p with p.age=20'`

[more info here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html/ch11.html#ql-select-clause)

Comment: Unfortunately it always returns all the rows for student that belong to given course. These are my annotations for joins:

     @OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL,       CascadeType.REMOVE}, fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "student")  

@ManyToOne()
private Student student

Comment: sorry about that... try adding distinct in there

Comment: actually are you trying to have the hibernate entity default to this join or are you actually creating an hql query and passing it to createQuery () on the hibernate session (or entityManager depending on what spec you are writting to)? There are annotations you can use to force hibernate the filter the join on the entity by default but then you have limited your ability to get access to all the objects in the db. If you arent, creating the hql query would be the way to go.

Comment: natedennis - I am trying to write hql query and pass it in @Query() annotation in my CrudRepository. Even when I write select distinct c from Course c inner join c.student p with p.age=20 I will still get all students for this course, I guess because ther eis at least one student that is 20 (but not all of them)

Comment: while this is mostly an hql question, we might get there faster if you post your entities and the code you are using to reference this query. I've reread the question and might understand what you are trying to do, but i believe you might be going about it the wrong way. (why you are here :)

Comment: Really appreciate it natedennis :) I editted my question

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c.name, s.id
FROM course c
INNER JOIN student s ON c.id = s.course_id
WHERE s.age = 20
```